# Pulling functions inside an integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have the relationship $\int_E h d\mu = \int_E d\nu$ for some integrable function $h$ and measures $\nu$ and $\mu$. I then multiply both sides of the equation with some other integrable function $g$ and then plug it inside the integrals to get

$$\int_Eg h d\mu = \int_E gd\nu$$

It seems intuitive to me but is that allowed for any $g$? I know I can do it with constants and Lebesgue integrals, but I'm not sure it's allowed for functions. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this hold for every measurable set $E$?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. For instance
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sin x\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}0\,dx=0,
$$
but
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sin x\times\sin x\,dx\ne\int_0^{2\pi}\sin x\times0\,dx.
$$

Comment: I see... What if I drop the definite part

Comment: Does $$\int h d\mu = \int d\nu$$ imply $$\int g h d\mu = \int g d\nu$$

Comment: For general measures it does not make sense. $\int h\,dx$ is a primitive of $h$.